# UICollectionView on top of a UITableView in separate child view controllers

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

My view hierarchy is as follows.

```
ParentContainerVC    
..UINavigationViewController (child of ParentContainerVC)
....UITableViewController (child of navigation view controller)
..UICollectionViewController (child of ParentContainerVC)
```

Scroll events are being intercepted correctly by the VC hosting the UICollectionView, but the UITableView underneath remains frozen. Both are sized to take the full width / height of the screen, but should be allowed to scroll independently (the UICollectionView does not obscure the UITableView underneath, in case you're wondering - but the user needs to be able to scroll both at the same time).

In the VC hosting the collection view, I have implemented:

```
extension UICollectionViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

However this did not help. I assume this is because the view controller has been added as a child controller and this won't work across sibling view controllers.

The `ParentContainerVC` is simply a container view controller with the two children. What do I have to do to get the touch / scroll events to work across the two children / siblings independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a little tricky but I figured it out eventually. The problem essentially is that once a view (depth first) passes for a hit-test, other views behind or around the hit-tested view stop receiving touches.

The trick is to add yet another dummy `UIView` in front of all other content to orchestrate and merge all touches. Then grab the `.panGestureRecognizer` from each of the `UIScrollView` / `UICollectionView` / `UITableView` child view controllers, and add them to this dummy view controller.

Now, all scrollable lists no matter where in the view hierarchy begin to scroll and respond to touches, without fiddling with `hitTest` or subclassing.

To further refine which scroll view reacts on touch first, you could add another `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and then do something like `.require(toFail: myNewPanGesture)` along with an implementation of how and when you'd like this gesture to fail. This way you can control the scrollable content you'd like to scroll first.